# Fastest way to capitalize the first word in a string (base)

Tags: regex, r

Using the base install functions what is the fastest way to capitalize the first letter in a vector of text strings?

I have provided a solution below but it seems to be a very inefficient approach (using substring and pasting it all together).  I'm guessing there's a regex solution I'm not thinking of.

Once I have a few responses I'll benchmark them and report back the fastest solution using microbenchmarking.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
x <- c("i like chicken.", "mmh so good", NA)
#desired output
[1] "I like chicken." "Mmh so good"     NA
```

Answer (score 5):

I didn't time it, but I bet this is pretty fast

```
capitalize <- function(string) {
    #substring(string, 1, 1) <- toupper(substring(string, 1, 1))
    substr(string, 1, 1) <- toupper(substr(string, 1, 1))
    string
}
capitalize(x)
#[1] "I like chicken." "Mmh so good"     NA
```

Comment: Very nice I like it.  Didn't know you could assign to substring +1

Comment: just compared it against `substr`; `substring` is marginally faster

Comment: hmmm, on second look, `substr` is faster

Comment: which is what would be expected since `substring` calls `substr` after doing some other stuff.

Answer (score 4):

I think this will be slowest, but let it race against other solutions:

```
capitalize<-function(string) {
   sub("^(.)","\\U\\1", string, perl=TRUE )
}  

x <- c("i like chicken.", "mmh so good", NA)
capitalize(x)
```

EDIT: actually on [ideone](http://ideone.com/5hbtX) it is faster than substring

EDIT 2: matching any lowercase letter turns out to be slightly slower:

```
sub("^(\\p{Ll})","\\U\\1", string, perl=TRUE)
```

Comment: Don't worry, I didn't take it to heart. Just not much point having the same answer twice! :-P

Comment: i think so as well, i have no R available right now so i could only run it on ideone

Answer (score 3):

The `Hmisc` package contains a [`capitalize`](http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/Hmisc/html/capitalize.html) function:

```
> require(Hmisc)
> capitalize(c("i like chicken.", "mmh so good", NA))
[1] "I like chicken." "Mmh so good"     NA
```

(Although this appears to be slower than both the `substring` and regular expression versions.)

Comment: +1 Seeing that it uses `substr` internally led me to re-test mine, and now I'm getting better results with `substr` than with `substring`

Answer (score 1):

My solution using substring:

```
capitalize <- function(string) {
    cap <-  function(x) {
        if (is.na(x)) {
            NA
        }
        else {
            nc <- nchar(x)
            paste0(toupper(substr(x, 1, 1)), substr(x, 
              2, nc))
        }
    }
    sapply(string, cap, USE.NAMES = FALSE) 
}

x <- c("i like chicken.", "mmh so good", NA)
capitalize(x)
```